# Time Circle Animation for Android App

Tags: java, android, animation, geometry

How can I implement an animation in Android Studio where a circle "closes" in a specific interval (30 seconds) like that and repeat itself?

[image: Animation screenshot 1]

[image: Animation screenshot 2]

Comment: there are exact libraries available.just search for it.

Comment: Your answer is here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381474/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-animation-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself (It's quite fun) then here's what you need:

Create a custom view, in the onDraw(Canva canvas) method, you need to:

- draw a grey circle, centered in your view.
- draw a blue arc, it's angle being a percentage of 360 describing the percentage of time which has happened (this should be backed by a timing mechanism)
- draw a light blue circle (same colour as the parent) with the same center as both above.
- Either draw text (or, can be slightly easier, create a child TextView and layer it ontop).

The code for all of those things is pretty easy to find on SO.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that helped me :)