# What is the best way to implement custom animation on android?

Tags: android, animation

I'm trying to implement animation which draws a circle. It should look something like this gif except the color of the line should be all solid. Also my circle should start from 0 degrees and finish at 360. Any ideas ideas how to implement this? Examples would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: use `ObjectAnimator` / `ValueAnimator`

Comment: check this library https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View. Also this question is offtopic

Answer (score 3):

At its most basic level, this is the result of the [`drawArc()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint)) method called on a `Canvas`, either inside a `View` or a `Drawable`.

In respect to the animation, you can achieve it by using a `ValueAnimator` that sets the `sweepAngle` parameter used in the `drawArc()` method inside an [`AnimatorUpdateListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener.html)

**Edit:** For example, you would call `getAnimatedFraction()` on the Update Listener's `ValueAnimator` argument, which returns a `float` value beteween `0F` and `1F`, and multiply this by the target degree you would like to achieve (i.e. `300`). Then use it to set the `sweepAngle` and `invalidate` the `View` to redraw it.

Comment: Thanks. I also found this sample which was really helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29381788/1329901

Comment: @Egidijus Yup! There's a few ways to do it to be fair. You could also create a custom `Drawable` and have it implement `Animatable`, but I prefer the methods outlined in my answer and the one in your link.