# Drawing circle gradually in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-design-library

I want to show a circle being drawn in android gradually like this:

[image]

How should i start? 
What needs to be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381474/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-animation-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
 ProgressBar p
 p=(PregressBar)findViewById(R.id.p);
 ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt (p, "progress", 0, 100);
    animation.setDuration (3000); 
    animation.setInterpolator (new DecelerateInterpolator ());
    animation.start ();`
```

Then in xml

```
  <ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/p"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="@dimen/progreess_circle"
android:layout_height="@dimen/progreess_circle"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:rotation="270"
android:progress="0"
android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```

Circular.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
android:shape="ring"
android:thickness="10sp" >
<solid android:color="@color/yellow_text_color" />
```