# How to show a custom indeterminate progress bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

i mean realy cool and complex stuff.

[image]
first i thinked on animated gif but that on the practice was so much laggy 
also on css with webview but that becomes really hard for responsive layout i think.
So how "the pros" do this?

note: I am new to android

Edit: this is exacty what i want to get

```css
*{width: 100%;
height: 100%;}
.sk-circle {
  
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child {
  width: 400%;
  height: 400%;

  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
}
.sk-circle .sk-child:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
          animation: sk-circleBounceDelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out both;
}
.sk-circle .sk-circle2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
          transform: rotate(30deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
          transform: rotate(60deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle5 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
          transform: rotate(120deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(150deg);
          transform: rotate(150deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle7 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle8 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(210deg);
          transform: rotate(210deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle9 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(240deg);
          transform: rotate(240deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle10 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
          transform: rotate(270deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle11 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(300deg);
          transform: rotate(300deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle12 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(330deg);
          transform: rotate(330deg); }
.sk-circle .sk-circle2:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
          animation-delay: -1.1s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle3:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
          animation-delay: -1s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle4:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
          animation-delay: -0.9s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle5:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
          animation-delay: -0.8s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle6:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.7s;
          animation-delay: -0.7s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle7:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
          animation-delay: -0.6s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle8:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.5s;
          animation-delay: -0.5s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle9:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
          animation-delay: -0.4s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle10:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.3s;
          animation-delay: -0.3s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle11:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
          animation-delay: -0.2s; }
.sk-circle .sk-circle12:before {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.1s;
          animation-delay: -0.1s; }

@-webkit-keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  } 40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes sk-circleBounceDelay {
  0%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
            transform: scale(0);
  } 40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loop.css">
  <title>:)</title>

</head>
<body background="#656565">
<div class="sk-circle">
  <div class="sk-circle1 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle2 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle3 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle4 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle5 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle6 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle7 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle8 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle9 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle10 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle11 sk-child"></div>
  <div class="sk-circle12 sk-child"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

but i need to have the ability of centrate into other view

Comment: PD: if is using CSS please explain how!

Comment: You just an animated object, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29381788/3825913