# Drawing animated circle upon an element in Android

Tags: android, animation

I'd like to draw an animated self-filling circle upon an element/button in Android. I found how to draw circles on custom classes or animating buttons, but I'm trying to draw an animated circle inside a button or something else like an imageview.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381474/how-to-draw-a-circle-with-animation-in-android-with-circle-size-based-on-a-value

Comment: This draws a circle on a custom view, now I'm trying to draw it on a default view.

Comment: what is a default view ?

Comment: Anything like a Button / Imageview etc.

Comment: you mean inside  a imageView? you can try to use DrawableLevels : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html